# Why can't I use scanf on the same variable again when the first trail fails

Tags: c, scanf

Please see the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int n;
    int i = scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("%d\n", i);
    int j = scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("%d\n", j);
    return 0;
}
```

Suppose I input a string for `n` at the first time, `scanf` will return `0`; however, why it won't allow me to input a value for `n` the second time and `j` is automatic `0`? What should I do to make it allow me to input a value for `n` again even if I typed a wrong value at the first time?

Comment: Your code is not allowing for a '\n' (newline) when you enter a value.  Suggest changing the scanf format string from "%d" to " %d" so it will skip over any white space (newline is a white space). Otherwise, the second call to scanf() is seeing the newline and stopping

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're almost certainly entering a non-numeric value, which will cause the first `scanf` to fail, returning zero and (this is the important bit) *leaving the stream pointer exactly where it was before the `scanf` call.*

That means the *next* time you call it, it will simply try to read the *same* data.

The return value of zero is a dead giveaway - `scanf` returns the number of items successfully scanned, so zero means you didn't give it a number.

If you enter *numbers,* it works fine, as per the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int n;
    int i = scanf("%d", &n);
    printf(">> %d %d\n", i, n);
    int j = scanf("%d", &n);
    printf(">> %d %d\n", j, n);
    return 0;
}
```

When you run that and enter `41` and `32`, you see:

```
41
>> 1 41
32
>> 1 32
```

Every C programmer at some point in their career comes up against the inadequacies of user input in that language. Your best bet for line based input is to simply find a function that does it well, then use `sscanf` on the resultant string.

One that ensures lines are the basic unit, and can handle buffer overflows and making sure excess data doesn't "corrupt" future input.

[Here's one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023895/how-to-read-string-entered-by-user-in-c/4023921#4023921) I prepared earlier.

Answer (score 1):

You can ignore the rest of the line before entering input afresh and reading them. You can ignore the rest of the line using:

```
scanf("%[^\n]*\n");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you enter numbers your code will work fine. However, when you are entering a string, then you must remove the string from input stream before using it again.

---

For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int n;
    char c;
    int i = scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("%d\n", i);
    //Remove the previous string from the input stream
    while ( (c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF );
    int j = scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("%d\n", j);
    return 0;
}
```

**Output when input is integer**

```
100
1
200
1
```

**Output when input is strings**

```
abcd
0
efghi
0
```

For further reference: [Why does everyone say not to use scanf? What should I use instead?](http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html)

Comment: You might want to slightly adjust the wording. It's not the newline that needs to be removed, it's the non-numeric input (though the easiest way to do this is to skip everything up to and including the newline). The newline will be skipped by the next `scanf` anyway because it's whitespace.

Comment: @paxdiablo: Thanks for the correct suggestion. Made the changes. Your answer is better than mine :)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! But I may not understand what this line of code does:     while ( (c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF ); it seems that nothing is within the while loop.

Answer (score 1):

The non-numeric string you entered isn't consumed by `scanf`.

Instead, you can use `fgets` and `sscanf` like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int n;
    char str[100];
    fgets(str, sizeof(str), stdin);
    int i = sscanf(str, "%d", &n);
    printf("%d\n", i);
    fgets(str, sizeof(str), stdin);
    int j = sscanf(str, "%d", &n);
    printf("%d\n", j);
    return 0;
}
```